# RewriteRule and RewriteCond not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am tring to retwite:

```
http://example.com/industry/fn/bpo-jobs
```

to

```
http://example.com/industry.php?fn=bpoobs
```

and similarly:

```
http://example.com/industry/cat/obs
```

to

```
http://example.com/industry.php?cat=obs
```

Using following rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)fn=(.*)(&|$) 
RewriteRule ^industry/fn/(\w+)$ industry.php?fn=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)cat=(.*)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^industry/cat/(\w+)$ industry.php?cat=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

But it is not working properly, I think it is treating

```
 http://example.com/industry/fn/bpo-jobs
```

as

```
http://example.com/industry.php
```

Need help to resolve it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the RewriteCond statements.

Try this (without the RewriteCond):

```
RewriteRule ^industry/fn/(\w+)$ industry.php?fn=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^industry/cat/(\w+)$ industry.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

Or, more simply, this:

```
RewriteRule ^industry/(cat|fn)/(\w+)$ industry.php?$1=$2 [L]
```